# Searching for an "intuitive" explanation about how gravitational waves can be detected by a laser interferometer like LIGO

Tags: general-relativity, time, interference, ligo, gravitational-wave-detectors

Since LIGO's first detection of gravitational waves, I have been searching for an intuitive way -as long as intuition can be useful in relativity, which often it isn't- to understand how the detector works. More specifically, a way to understand how gravitational waves can be detected even when the measuring ruler (laser light pulses with a fixed wavelenght) is stretched and shrunk as anything else affected by the wave. I've read [the standard answer provided by the LIGO team](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/faq), and [the heuristic answer of Peter Saulson](https://www.aapt.org/doorway/tgrutalks/Saulson/SaulsonTalk-Teaching%20gravitational%20waves.pdf), which are great. Both explanations rely mostly on time, which led me to a tentative interpretation that goes as follows:

Let's say that the big interferometer is not a ruler with two arms, but rather two light clocks, in which the ticks are replaced by reflections on the mirrors. In absence of gravitational waves, both clocks are synchronized. When a gravitational wave crosses the perpendicular arms, though, the distance between the mirrors -whose detection might be problematic as stated before- changes, but so does the time between reflections, in order to keep invariant the relativistic interval (which for light motion is zero). The gravitational wave affects the two arms -light clocks- differently, so they get out of sync producing an interferometric effect when the beams are reunited in the detector.

I haven't found any literature about LIGO with this interpretation, so I guess is either self evident or simply wrong. What do you think?

Answer (score 10):

Your explanation in terms of light travel time is correct (and actually I would say better than the usual explanation in terms of changing lengths).

However, a key point is that gravitational waves stretch space for **inertial** (freely-falling) particles. The particles in a ruler are not freely falling, they are bound together by electromagnetic forces. Therefore, a gravitational wave will stretch a meter stick differently than it would stretch the distance between two freely floating particles that were 1 meter apart before the gravitational wave passed. The fact that there is an interplay between the "strain force" of a gravitational wave and the internal forces holding an object together is the basis of resonant bar gravitational-wave detectors. Anyway, this is all to say that you could in principle use a ruler to measure the displacement of freely falling particles due to a passing gravitational wave, because they are not stretched by the same amount.